# Instantiating anonymous inner classes in Java with additional interface implementation

Tags: java, subclassing, anonymous-inner-class, interface-implementation

Let's say I have the following two class/interface definitions:

```java
public abstract class FooClass {
    public abstract void doFoo();
}
```

and

```java
public interface BarInterface {
    public void doBar();
}
```

If I want to make an anonymous inner class that extends/implements both, do I need to do this:

```java
public abstract class BothClass extends FooClass implements BarInterface {}

...

new BothClass() {
    public void doFoo() {
        System.out.println("Fooooooooo!!!!");
    }

    public void doBar() {
        System.out.println("Baaaaaaaar!!!!");
    }
}.doBar();
```

Or is there a short-cut that allows me to not define `BothClass`? Something like this, maybe:

```java
new (FooClass implements BarInterface)() {
    public void doFoo() {
        System.out.println("Fooooooooo!!!!");
    }

    public void doBar() {
        System.out.println("Baaaaaaaar!!!!");
    }
}.doBar();
```

(This idea gives me several errors, none of which are helpful here)

Comment: Make `FooClass` implement `BarInterface`? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @JoshM: Let's say I can't/don't want to make `FooClass` implement `BarInterface`.

Comment: There is no shortcut.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9

Comment: @MarkusA. Anonymous classes are implementations of existing class definitions. If you wanted both, you'd need a class defined with both as in your first example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Let's go to the JLS:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)

> An anonymous class declaration is automatically derived from a class
>   instance creation expression by the Java compiler.

where a class instance creation expression is

```
ClassInstanceCreationExpression:
    new TypeArgumentsopt TypeDeclSpecifier TypeArgumentsOrDiamondopt
                                                            ( ArgumentListopt ) ClassBodyopt
    Primary . new TypeArgumentsopt Identifier TypeArgumentsOrDiamondopt
                                                            ( ArgumentListopt ) ClassBodyopt

TypeArgumentsOrDiamond:
    TypeArguments
    <> 

ArgumentList:
    Expression
    ArgumentList , Expression
```

So, no, the Java language specification does not allow any shortcuts for making your anonymous class implement more interfaces than the type you're sub-typing.

So, to [determine the type of the anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1)

> If the class instance creation expression ends in a class body, then
>   the class being instantiated is an anonymous class. Then:
>
> - If T denotes an interface, then an anonymous direct subclass of Object
>     that implements the interface named by T is declared.
>
> [...]
>
> - Let T be the type named by the Identifier and any type arguments. An
>     anonymous direct subclass of the class named by T is declared. The
>     body of the subclass is the ClassBody given in the class instance
>     creation expression.

Your alternative is the way to do it.

You can also use [local classes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous class

```
FooClass f = new FooClass() {
  public void doFoo() {}
};
```

is just a convenient shorthand for a local class definition with a generated name

```
class $anon extends FooClass {
  public void doFoo() {}
}
FooClass f = new $anon();
```

If you want to implement interfaces just write the local class definition explicitly

```
class LocalFoo extends FooClass implements BarInterface {
  // method declarations here
}
LocalFoo lf = new LocalFoo();
```