# Can we declare interface inside a method?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class, local-class, nested-types

"You cannot declare an interface inside a block; interfaces are inherently static" This is sentence from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#local-classes-are-similar-to-inner-classes

However, I can declare an interface in the code below. I can also create an anonymous class by extending the interface.

```
public void testing() {
    
    interface LocalInterface {
        void prints();
    }
    
    LocalInterface localInterface = new LocalInterface() {

        @Override
        public void prints() {
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }};
        localInterface.prints();
}
```

Comment: It depends on the [JDK version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66320618/6650475).

Comment: Note that those Oracle tutorials are all "_written for JDK 8_". Quite a bit has changed since then (the current GA version is 21.0.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Java 16+

It depends on which JDK you are using. The `interface`-inside-a-method feature was introduced in [JDK 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16). Ditto for `enum` and `record`. See [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

If you are using IntelliJ, it will show you an error when JDK is set to 8. The error says: `Local interfaces are not supported at language level '8'`, and the suggestion is upgrade to JDK 16+.

[image]